# Prove that on every great circle on the earth there are antipodal points at which the temperature is the same.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Prove that on every great circle on the earth there are antipodal points at which the temperature is the same.  Assume that the surface of the earth is a sphere and that the temperature is a continuous function.

---

Side note: This question is on an assignment focusing on connectedness and path-connectedness of sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$ but I'm not sure how this relates. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for this [intermediate value theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)?

Answer (score 5):

Let $\phi(x) = t(x)-t(-x)$, where $t$ is the temperature function.

Since $\phi$ is continuous and $\phi(x) = - \phi(x)$ we can use the
intermediate value theorem to find some $y$ such that $\phi(y) = 0$.

Comment: The argument is well known, but you've proved that there is one great circle with the given property.  The OP wanted to show that there is a pair of points on every great circle.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I am well aware that this a well known argument, I am not claiming any uniqueness. I haven't mentioned any specific great circle, so I am not sure what your point is? By $x$ above I mean $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Show: Given a great circle, find an antipodal pair of points on that great circle with the same temperature.  In this case we need Borsuk-Ulam in case $n=1$, don't we?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: No, you only need the fact that a great circle is connected, then the range of $\phi$ above is connected, hence an interval that contains $0$. Then $\phi^{-1} \{0 \}$ must contain a pair of antipodal points. Borsuk Ulam is severe overkill here, and gives us no new information (since we are really dealing with $S^1$). As an aside, the purpose was to give the OP a hint rather than explicitly giving all of the details.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

[image]

Hint 2:

> Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sledgehammer you can hit it with, if you've already covered it in your course: the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) lets you conclude exactly what you want. The theorem says that any continuous $S^n \to \mathbb{R}$ maps some pair of antipodal points to the same value.

For $n=1$ however, as other answers show, you don't need such heavy machinery, and the intermediate value theorem does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

let f(x) = temperature at x - temperature at antipode of x.

f(antipode of x) = -f(x)

If we assume changes in temperatures are gradual with location, we can claim f is continuous.

if f(a) > 0 for some a then f(a at antipode) = -f(a) < 0

Intermediate value theorem says f(x) = 0 for some value of x.